# Unable to load css file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, nunjucks

I am using express and nunjucks template engine for building a node app.

**templateEngine.js**

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');

module.exports = function (app) {
    // store environment env
    var env = nunjucks.configure(['views/www'], {
        autoescape: true,
        express   : app
    });
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express=require('express'),
    app=express(),
    engines = require('consolidate'),
    nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    http = require("http"),
    assert = require('assert');
    require('./templateEngine.js')(app);

app.set('view engine', 'html');

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/firstDb",function(err,db){
  assert.equal(null,err);
    console.log("Sucessfully Connected to the Server");
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var query = {name : 'nobody'};
    db.collection('friends').find().toArray(function(err,docs){
      console.log(docs)
      res.render('index',{'friendNames':docs})
    })
  })
})

var server = app.listen(3000,function(){
  var port=server.address().port;
  console.log('Express server listening on port', port);
})
```

When I tried to load

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in index.html it says cannot get "http://localhost:3000/css/style.css"

my folder structure is

```
Root
  views
    www
     css
       style.css
     index.html
  app.js
  templateEngine.js
```

If anybody encountered this error earlier, please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `http://localhost:3000/views/www/css/style.css` ?

Comment: no no, in index.html I gave it as css/style.css. so in console it is showing the same. even if I give it as "views/www/css/style.css", it is not working

Comment: since my index.html is in www folder, i haven't add "views/www" to href of link lag

Comment: If you acces the url directly in the browser doe you see the `css`file? Only console errors?

Comment: You should use something like this app.use(express.static('filePath'));
Look at documentation. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @daan.desmedt it says cannot get css/style.css

Comment: thanku, all the static files will be loaded from "public" folder. so it is required to put all the files in public folder and give the path